# How to convert a file into a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, dictionary

I am attempting to write a python program for a personalised recommendation service for books based on a similarity algorithm, where recommendations are made based on ratings of a number of books from other users/readers.

I want to write a section of the program that reads data from two input files:
books.txt which includes a list of 55 books in an author,title format, one entry per line. I want convert this file into a list in the form;

```
[["Author", "title"], [...]]
```

The second file ratings.txt includes usernames to represent users of the service followed by a list of 55 integers, each representing a rating for each book from books.txt, in the same order. The file is structured using the following format:

```
user_a\n  user_a_rating_1 ...  user_a_rating_55 \n
```

And I want to convert the file into a dictionary in the form;

```
{"username":[0, 1, 2, 3], "user":[ratings...]}
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What did you try? Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely check out `pandas` and the [read_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) function. That puts each time into a data frame and from there you can call the [to_dict](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) method on each column if you need to.